# Exclude lines from output based on patterns in file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, pattern-matching

I have a couple of IP addresses in a text file. I have another file in which each line contains an IP along with some other data. Samples below,

**pattern.txt (the IPs to exclude) :**

```
A.B.C.D
E.F.G.H
I.J.K.L
```

**target.txt (the main list) :**

```
server1,L.M.N.O,user1
server2,A,B.C.D,user2
server3,P.Q.R.S,user3
```

Now I need to create a rule (preferably a one-liner) which lists only those lines in "target.txt", whose IP addresses are **NOT** present in "pattern.txt". The required output is as below,

```
server1,L.M.N.O,user1
server3,P.Q.R.S,user3
```

I tried using this `cat target.txt | grep -f pattern.txt`. This doesn't get the job done though: it simply highlights the IPs I want to exclude, but doesn't actually **exclude** them from the output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps try using the -v switch with grep to exclude the strings. Also note that you don't need cat, simple grep -v -f pattern.txt target.txt should work.

Comment: @tvm Yes, I tried this as well - `cat target.txt | grep -vf pattern.txt`, but it only produces a blank output :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

```
grep -F -v -f pattern.txt target.txt
```

Supplying `-F` would interpret the patterns as fixed strings, so `.` in the IP addressed wouldn't match any *arbitrary* character.

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: So just to clear my head, each line in the pattern file was interpreted as an individual regex and the dot was therefore processed as such. Now, the `-F` flag treats each line as a simple string and nothing more, which is resulting in correct matching.

Comment: @JTG Yes, without `-F` the `.` would have been considered a regex metacharacter.  Depending upon your input, it might have done unwanted things.